# How to identify and list Circular Reference elements in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, circular-reference

I have an employee , manager hierarchy which could end up being circular.

Ex:
28397468N>88518119N>87606705N>28397468N

```
Create Table emp_manager (  Emp_id varchar(30), Manager_id varchar(30));

Insert into emp_manager    values ('28397468N','88518119N');

Insert into emp_manager    values ('88518119N','87606705N');

Insert into emp_manager    values ('87606705N','28397468N');
```

My requirement is:
When my proc is called and there are circular hierarchies in the emp_manager table, we should return an error listing the employees in the hierarchy.

The below link contains some useful info:
https://mccalljt.io/blog/2017/01/postgres-circular-references/

I have modified it as below:

```
select * from (
WITH RECURSIVE circular_managers(Emp_id, Manager_id, depth, path, cycle) AS (
SELECT u.Emp_id, u.Manager_id, 1,
ARRAY[u.Emp_id],
false
FROM emp_manager u  
UNION ALL
SELECT u.Emp_id, u.Manager_id, cm.depth + 1,
(path || u.Emp_id)::character varying(32)[],
u.Emp_id = ANY(path)
FROM emp_manager u, circular_managers cm
WHERE u.Emp_id = cm.Manager_id AND NOT cycle
)
select
     distinct (path) d
FROM circular_managers
WHERE cycle
AND path[1] = path[array_upper(path, 1)]) cm
```

BUT, the problem is, it is returning all combinations of the hierarchy:

```
{28397468N,88518119N,87606705N,28397468N}
{87606705N,28397468N,88518119N,87606705N}
{88518119N,87606705N,28397468N,88518119N}

I need a simple answer like this:

28397468N>88518119N>87606705N>28397468N

even this will do:
28397468N>88518119N>87606705N
```

Please help!

Comment: I don't understand from where appears  id='28397468N' in results. I don't see an  `INSERT` with such value. Did you missed it i?

Comment: I modified the question to be coherent with the data now. Please check.

Comment: What do you mean by "*SORT doesn't work since my employee IDs are VARCHAR and not INT*"? Sure you can `ORDER BY` a varchar column just like an integer column.

Comment: "*My requirement is: When my proc is called and there are circular hierarchies*" - what procedure are you talking about? Is it a trigger that should prevent such circular references from occurring by throwing an exception upon insert/update? Is it a stored view that should just list the circles?

Comment: It is a part of a stored procedure that should list each unique circle if there are circular references. I have added my SQL in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all references:

```
{28397468N,88518119N,87606705N,28397468N}
{87606705N,28397468N,88518119N,87606705N}
{88518119N,87606705N,28397468N,88518119N}
```

are correct but just start from different element.

> I need a simple answer like this: 28397468N>88518119N>87606705N>28397468N

So what's needed is a filter for the same circle refs.

Let's do that in a way:

- sort distinct items in arrays
- aggregate them back - so for all references it will be  '{28397468N,87606705N,88518119N}'
- use produced value for DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE

```sql
WITH D (circle_ref ) AS (
VALUES
('{28397468N,88518119N,87606705N,28397468N}'::text[]),
('{87606705N,28397468N,88518119N,87606705N}'::text[]),
('{88518119N,87606705N,28397468N,88518119N}'::text[])
), ordered AS (
SELECT 
        D.circle_ref,
        (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT el ORDER BY el) FROM  UNNEST(D.circle_ref) AS el ) AS ordered_circle
    FROM 
        D
)
SELECT DISTINCT
        FIRST_VALUE (circle_ref) OVER (PARTITION BY ordered_circle ORDER BY circle_ref) AS circle_ref 
    FROM 
        ordered;
```

| circle_ref |
| --- |
| {28397468N,88518119N,87606705N,28397468N} |

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ytb2v11s8T95PPLoTZZed/0

Answer (score 0):

To prevent circular references, you can use a closure table and a trigger - as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802
The closure table will also allow you to easily get all subordinates for a given supervisor (no matter how deep in the hierarchy) - or all direct bosses of a given employee (up to the root).

Before using the `rebuild_tree` stored procedure you will have to remove all circular references from the hierarchy.